# How to properly fetch async data in React when using the map() method?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, es6-promise

I have a list of posts that I am mapping through and want to get the associated author data and avatar photo url, for each post. I have functions that make api calls and return this information, when called on each post. Then the username, full_name & avatar_url are added to the post, so that when rendering the data in the component, all of the data is available.

**See the custom hook:**

```
// Custom hook to fetch the user & avatar for each post and combine them
function usePostsWithUserDetails(posts) {
  const [combinedPosts, setCombinedPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make async call for session & avatar_url that match the post
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const combineData = posts.map(async (post) => {
        const [user, avatar] = await Promise.all([
          getSessionProfile(post.user_id),
          fetchProfileAvatar(post.user_id),
        ]);
        // Add the needed data to the post
        post.username = user.username;
        post.full_name = user.full_name;
        post.avatar_url = avatar;
      });

      setCombinedPosts(combineData);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [])

  return combinedPosts;
}
```

So my problem is that when I go to add the data to the post (ie: post.username = user.username), that data may not have been returned from the async function. I am fairly new to React and still haven't gotten the hang of how to return the promise when it's needed.

I believe you would normally want to add the data, after it's returned from the useEffect. This issue being that this needs to happen for each post. The only other solution I can think of is to have the needed data added to the table when the post is created but at some point I am going to need to query other tables and combine data.

Any direction is much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your map in a `Promise.all`. Also you should `return` the modified post in the map loop.

```js
function getSessionProfile() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({
      username: 'bob',
      full_name: 'Billy Bob'
    })
  })
}

function fetchProfileAvatar() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve('https://avatar.com')
  })
}

const posts = [{ id: 1 }]

const combineData = () => Promise.all(posts.map(async (post) => {
  const [user, avatar] = await Promise.all([
    getSessionProfile(post.user_id),
    fetchProfileAvatar(post.user_id),
  ]);
  
  return {
    ...post,
    // Add the needed data to the post
    username: user.username,
    full_name: user.full_name,
    avatar_url: avatar,  
  }
}));

(async () => {
  const combinedData = await combineData()
  console.log(combinedData)
})()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have helped me over a big hurdle. My bad on not returning the post. Mistake there.

Comment: so strange, it was working but upon refresh it's returning an array of promises instead. :-( 

The solution I posted below is what I was used and it worked for a few reloads but now goes returning promises. I will try your solution above and report back, then change my answer below. I thought I could do it all in one function and for a moment it appeared to work.

Comment: @Chris your line here `Promise.all([posts.map(` should be `Promise.all(posts.map(` since map already returns an array

Comment: thank you. For some reason the loading of the data isn't consistent. Half of the time the array that I console.log returns empty but sometimes it does return the data so I am not certain where I went wrong. I will try the separate function method you posted above and see how that works. I don't think the problem is with the functions calling the API but I added those below in update one.

Comment: ok so I guess mine works as intended, as long as I put posts in the dependency array of the useEffect. Fairly new to development and it seems this is just the nature of async calls. You can't be sure how long it takes the data to return. Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

**Update One:**  (using some hints from Dominic to try and fit it all in one function)

```
// Custom hook to fetch the user & avatar for each post and combine them
function usePostsWithUserDetails(posts) {
  const [combinedPosts, setCombinedPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make async call for session & avatar_url that match the post
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const combineData = await Promise.all(posts.map(async (post) => {
        const [user, avatar] = await Promise.all([
          getSessionProfile(post.user_id),
          fetchProfileAvatar(post.user_id),
        ]);
        
        post.username = user[0].username;
        post.full_name = user[0].full_name;
        post.avatar_url = avatar;

        return post
      }));

      setCombinedPosts(combineData);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [posts])

  return combinedPosts;
}
```

Functions from apiService to fetch the profile and avatar from Supabase:

```
export async function getSessionProfile(userId) {
  let { data: profiles, error } = await supabase
  .from('profiles')
  .select('*')
  .eq('id', userId);

  return profiles;
}
```

Fetch Avatar:

```
export async function fetchProfileAvatar (userId) {
  const avatarList = await listFilesInBucket('avatars', '');

  const avatarExists = avatarList.filter((avatar) => {
    return avatar.name.includes(userId);
  });

  const avatarURL = avatarExists[0].name ? await getImageURL('avatars', avatarExists[0].name).then(data => data.publicUrl) : '/static/default-avatar.png';

  return avatarURL;
}
```